# How can a user with gold and silver badges have only 1 reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

I recently visited a Stack Overflow user's profile. He has 19 gold badges, 90+ silver badges and 160+ bronze badges, but his reputation is 1. I wonder how this is happening. As I am new to this, what is the explanation?

Comment: Ok , If he is temporarily banned his reputation will be 1 ? and he wont loose his badges ?

Comment: @yellowantphil Thanks for the reply :) That post clarified all my doubts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This user is in the [Penalty box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256420/295232), as explained on Meta Stack Exchange:

> #### Penalty box
>
> When moderators determine that a user's actions are detrimental to the site they may suspend that user for a period of time. During this time "in the penalty box" the user will not be able to post questions or answers, and their reputation will be locked at 1 until the suspension expires. Any rep they gained over the ban time is gained when the ban ends - a reputation recount happens.

Apparently the badges are still visible during the penalty box time.

Comment: You answered clearly as before :)